# Sharepoint Designer Workflow - call http web service fails - Chinese File name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint Designer site Workflow.

In this workflow, there is an action "call Http web service" to copy files from one location to another.

**It fails for all the files that has chinese character in file name**.
I am getting error as "**Bad Request - Invalid URL**".

**For all other files (without chinese character in file name) it works perfectly.**

Anybody has any idea or suggestions for this scenario.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the default behavior. You need to encode the Chinese characters when using Rest API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here I am using call http web service action in SharePoint designer workflow. I know how to encode URL in JavaScript but I am not sure how to encode URL in SharePoint designer workflow. Could you please suggest me on that..